Sample Requirements for Covariance matrix Estimation
I have an input signal matrix $X$ of shape 4 x N, each row contains the same signal but with constant time delay (related to array signal processing)
$$X[i, :] = X(t-i\tau)$$
My goal is to find the inverse covariance matrix of the signal,
$$ R^{-1} = (XX^H)^{-1}$$
what I liked to know is that if there is any statistical method to find the minimum time samples required to make the matrix invertible and the maximum samples until the signal is no longer stationary.
The application is wireless comms, so at baseband, the $\mu_i = 0$ or close to zero and is ignored.
